# Where is CSS for jQuery UI's .ui-selected Defined?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm trying to apply jQuery UI Selectable to a portion of my website.  However, I do not see either the selection box while dragging the mouse, nor does the color of selected `li` elements change.

So to understand the problem, I went back to the source:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

I see (using IE9 developer tools) that a style `.ui-selected` is applied to selected elements.  Using Trace Styles, IE shows that `background-color` is originally defined in `jquery-ui.css` but overridden (ultimately) by `#selectable .ui-selected`.  However, IE does not show the source of `#selectable .ui-selected`.  Searching the jQuery UI style sheet I reference, `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css`, finds no mention of `ui-selected`, nor do I find it in `jquery.ui.selectable.css`.

Where exactly is the demo page getting the CSS for the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one of the other jQueryUI demos defines the style for those classes in a custom style sheet, so I ended up following that lead.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#serialize

It seems odd that those styles are not part of jQueryUI [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  Perhaps that will change in the future.